# Bluemix Android Push Notification unable to implement custom sound notification

Tags: android, audio, push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I'm trying to implement Bluemix Push Notification custom sound in Android with Mobile First Services Starter (MFSS) and/or Mobile App Builder. At the moment I can send simple push notifications to devices and works well.

The problem comes when I want to play a sound for notification.

With MFSS I'm trying using this code:

```
 MFPPushNotificationListener notificationListener = new MFPPushNotificationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final MFPSimplePushNotification message) 


        Log.e("message arrives", message.toString());
        NotificationManager notif = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        Notification noty = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setTicker("Entrando al area de ROPA")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_cast_dark)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentText("Hello World")
                .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notification))
                .setContentInfo("Set ContextInfo")
                .setContentTitle("Set title")
                .setContentInfo(message.getAlert().toString())
                .build();

        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(), 0);

        notif.notify(0, noty);
    }
};
```

On the other side also I'm trying using the IMF Push Service REST API with this payload the messages arrives but doesn't play the sound::

```
{
    "message": {
    "alert": "mensaje"
},

"settings": {
    "gcm": {
        "payload": {
            "sound": "notification.wav"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Finally from the push notification dashboard I'm using the documentation payload, also the messages arrives but doesn't play the sound:

```
 "settings":{
     "gcm":{
     "sound":"notification.wav",
  }
 }
```

Note: I'm created the raw folder in order to save the notification.wav file, also I'm implementing a button click listener in order to test the sound file and works well, the sound it's clear.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: We have been having issues with this as well and have brought it to the developers' attention. More updates to come

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested Push notifications with sound on the [latest version of the Android Push SDK](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-clientsdk-android-push), and got it working with my Android phone.

Here is initializing my application:
[image]

Here is my sound file:
[image]

Here was my request:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, I see that the new version 2.0.1 of push notification now works well using the push message dashboard.

However my app use NODE-RED inspired in this tutorial: 

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-nodered-push-app/ 

In order to send push notification with a custom payload and I noticed that, the push message for some reason not always arrives to the devices, also I tried using the IMF Push Service REST API  with the same result.

https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/imfpushrestapidocs/#!/messages/post_apps_applicationId_messages

Regards,

Comment: Are you using an emulator or a real device?

Comment: I'm using a real device (Huawei Ascend)

Comment: Could you create a new question with your new issue? (That way others can find out how to solve the problem if they encounter the same issue.)

Answer (score 0):

As of a few hours ago, version 2.0.1 of the Bluemix android push sdk was published to support notification sound.

Keep in mind, you will need to save your sound file in the `res/raw` directory and then you will be able use the documented payload like you mention:

```
"settings":{
     "gcm":{
     "sound":"notification.wav",
  }
 }
```

Apologies for the delay/confusion.